# Trouble with joining tables together

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to join tables by using Django queryset, but for some reason it keeps throwing an error.

Tables are structured as below.

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    P_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    P_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    P_userkey = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    P_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objects = models.Manager()

class User_info(models.Model):
    U_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    U_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    U_img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    U_info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    U_sudate = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    P_key = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

This is the code written to join two tables together.

```
queryset = User_info.objects.all().prefetch_related("Platform")
queryset = User_info.objects.all().select_related("Platform")
queryset = Platform.objects.all().select_related("User_info")
```

And the following is the error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in
>   select_related: 'Platform'. Choices are: P_key.

I've tried a number of query sets but I wasn't able to get far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use field names

```
queryset = User_info.objects.all().prefetch_related("P_key")
queryset = User_info.objects.all().select_related("P_key")
```